# C++: Conditions not being applied to simple nested if-then-else statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

Basically, this program outputs what candy a person should have, based on their responses to the prompts. If they like chocolate, the program asks if they like nuts. If they say yes to chocolate and no to nuts, they get M&M's. If they say yes to chocolate and nuts, they get peanut M&Ms. If they say no to chocolate, they get Skittles.

No matter what I put in for chocLover, I get Skittles as the output.

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SNACK_SIZE = 15;
    const int DRINK_SIZE = 6;


    char guestName[30];
    int  guestAge;
    char chocLover;
    char nutLover;

    int  count;

    char snack[15];
    char drink[6];

    for(count = 1; count <=12; count=count+1)
    {
    cout << left << "Guest #" << count << ":" << endl;

    cout << setw(31) << "What is your friend's name?";
    cin.getline(guestName,30);

    cout << setw(31) << "How old is your friend?";
    cin  >> guestAge;

    cout << setw(31) << "Do they like chocolate (Y/N)?";
    cin.get(chocLover);
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');

    if(chocLover == 'Y')
    {
        cout << setw(31) << "Do they like nuts (Y/N)?";
        cin.get(nutLover);

        if(nutLover == 'Y')
        {
            strncpy(snack,"Peanut M & M\'s",SNACK_SIZE);
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy(snack,"M & M\'s",SNACK_SIZE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy(snack,"Skittles",SNACK_SIZE);
    }

    if(guestAge <= 21)
    {
        if(guestAge < 6)
        {
            strncpy(drink,"juice",DRINK_SIZE);
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy(drink,"soda",DRINK_SIZE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy(drink,"wine",DRINK_SIZE);
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "You should serve " << guestName << " " << snack << " and ";
    cout << drink << "." << endl << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Guest #1:
What is your friend's name?    Guest
How old is your friend?        18
Do they like chocolate (Y/N)?  Y

You should serve Guest Skittles and soda.


Guest #2:
What is your friend's name?    Guest
How old is your friend?        20
Do they like chocolate (Y/N)?  Y

You should serve Guest Skittles and soda.
```

And so forth until it reaches #12.

If I cout << chocLover; nothing prints as well.

Comment: Do you have to use `cin.get(chocLover)`?  This works for me: `cin >> chocLover;`.  It doesn't answer the question, but may serve as a fix for now?

Answer (score 2):

`cin.get(chocLover)` performs unformatted input, it's reading the newline that was entered as part of the previous input. Use a formatted input operator to ignore whitespace:

`cin >> chocLover;`